# Gmail add-on load an HTML page in the side panel

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I'm wondering whether it's currently possible to build a Gmail add-on which would have a possibility to load some HTML page into it?

For example, let's assume. I have a resource *someresource.com* which I very frequently use when I read my emails basically working with Gmail. I would like to have an add-on on the side where I could click and the *someresource.com* will be loaded into the side panel. This would be very useful in this case. BTW there is such possibility in Outlook, meaning to create such extension.

From what I see right now in Gmail I could use

```
CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl('https://someresource.com').setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
```

Basically, open my resource in a new browser window. However, maybe I missed something and there is the possibility to load it into the side panel directly.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Nope, can't be done. Google wants a unified add-on experience on both mobile and desktop, which means you must use CardService and Cardservice will not allow custom HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this doesn't seem possible.

Some of the functions in the CardService object support [limited HTML formatting](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting) for bold, italic, underline, etc.